# Difference between ''ato'' and ''mo'' to mean more/another

Tags: word-choice

I learned that ''another bottle (of beer) please'' is ''ato ippon kudasai''.

But I heard someone say in a Japanese drama ''mo ippon kudasai''.

I know ''mo'' from ''mo ichi do''.

What is the difference between ''ato/mo ippon kudasai ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

あと and もう mean the same thing in this situation, when used as 'a little bit' or 'another'. See the examples below meaning "Let's try just a bit more".

〇あと少し頑張りましょう

〇もう少し頑張りましょう

There is a situation where they are not interchangeable, and that's when you're using the other meaning of もう, "already". The following sentence means "I already wrote it." and only the first version is correct.

〇もう書きました。

×あと書きました。

Or when you're using another meaning of あと, "after".　The following means "How soon will you arrive?" (lit: After how long will you arrive). Only the second version is correct.

×もうどのくらいで着きますか。

〇あとどのくらいで着きますか。